# How can I auto-mount internal NTFS HDD to encrypted /home partition with fstab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, mount, fstab

Summary: I would like to auto-mount an internal HDD in my user home directory using `fstab`, but am unable to do so.

I am setting up a new Thinkpad development machine with dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10 on an (internal) SSD. Both operating systems appear to function normally.

My personal data is stored on an internal NTFS-formatted HDD which I would like to share between operating systems. Without configuration, auto-mount/read/write functions as expected when I boot into the Windows and Ubuntu desktops. On Ubuntu, the drive is accessible through a dekstop icon or through "Other Locations" in the Files application.

However, I would like to auto-mount the drive under `/home/<username>/data`. I decided to use `fstab` to achieve this.

First, I found the drive's UUID using `sudo blkid`. The drive is mounting as `sda` and contains two partitions, which `blkid` describes as follows:

```
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="32d4b204-4781-487b-baf2-9f49aca22b7e"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Data" UUID="D0AA5898AA587CC2" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="5a989f6c-fab3-44d8-ab26-6dea47454de4"
```

I don't know what the purpose or significance of the `sda1` partition is, but I'm only interested in `sda2`.

Although this is a single-user machine, I'd still like to set up restrictive options and permissions. Accordingly, I append the following line to `/etc/fstab`, ending with a blank newline:

```
UUID=D0AA5898AA587CC2   /home/<username>/data   ntfs    uid=<username>,gid=<username>,owner,umask=077,dmask=077,fmask=077,nosuid,dev,windows_names,auto    0       2
```

I have chosen to be verbose and explicit in my options rather than use `defaults`, because it should make it easier to understand and tweak when I come back later.

As far as I understand it, the chosen options function as follows:

- uid: sets me as the owning user
- gid: sets my group (containing me as the single member) as the owning group
- owner: allows only the owner (me) to mount the drive
- *mask: sets default permissions for files and folders that only the owner (me) can read/write/execute, and all others have no permissions
- nosuid: scripts and executables run with the permissions of the current user, not the file owner (more secure)
- dev: from `man mount`: "Interpret character or block special devices on the filesystem." This would appear necessary to interact with disks.
- windows_names: protects me from writing Windows-breaking names to maintain inter-OS compatibility.
- auto: auto-mount the filesystem on boot and with the `sudo mount -a` command.

Under this scheme, not only is `/home/<username>/data` empty, but although the drive still appears in the "Files" application, it, too, is now empty.

When I run `mount`, the relevant partition is reported as follows:

```
/dev/sda2 on /home/<username>/data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

So it seems the drive is still owned by root (`user_id=0`).

I have tried many, many permutations of options - including much more permissive options, to no avail. The only change is if I refer instead to the `PARTUUID` of the `sda2` partition, then an additional "drive" appears in the "Files" application, called "data" (note the lowercase "d"). However, this "drive" is only accessible by root.

What do I need to change to get this to work? During installation of Ubuntu, I chose to make a separate and encrypted `/home` partition - could this be interfering with the auto-mount on boot, since presumably it is not decrypted until I login as `<username>`?

### EDIT: mounting in unencrypted directory/partition

I tried mounting the HDD in an un-encrypted partition/directory to which `<username>` has `rwx` permissions (`/tmp/data`) by changing the `fstab` like so:

```
UUID=D0AA5898AA587CC2   /tmp/data   ntfs    permissions,uid=mixtrak,gid=mixtrak,owner,umask=077,dmask=077,fmask=077,nosuid,dev,windows_names,auto    0       2
```

As a result, the filesystem mounted there and indeed appears to have the appropriate owner, group, and permissions (from `ls -l`):

```
drwx------ 1 <username> <username> 4096 Dec 25 07:38 data
```

And I have confirmed the contents are readable/writable by `<username>`. So the partition encryption *does* appear to be the cause of my problems.

However, I'm still confused about one thing. When I check `mount`, the partition is described thus:

```
/dev/sda2 on /tmp/data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

The options, permissions and owner are very different from the specified mount options in `fstab` and those visible at the `/tmp/data` mount point using `ls -l`. Why is that? What are the implications?

A final question: is this question more likely to get traction over on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, or perhaps Server Fault?

Comment: "encrypted `/home` partition - could this be interfering?" – it's a reasonable assumption. Why won't you test it by mounting `/dev/sda2` elsewhere, e.g. `/mnt/data`? If it succeeds then just make a symlink to it in your `/home/<username>/`.

Comment: Thanks. Encryption does appear to be the cause, but apparently I also don't completely understand the `mount` output. Have updated question accordingly.